# Upload.aspx auto check/uncheck option to overwrite files from client side js/jquery

Tags: document-library, jquery, file-upload, modal-dialog

So if I reference the upload.aspx with guid, show that dialog from a link or something from a page, is there anyway I can get to the elements of that form? I only have javascript/jquery and designer to work with.

I would like to auto uncheck the overwrite, and hide that option like you can do on edit forms with jquery....something to that effect. is this possible without having access to the file system/layouts folder, etc?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a sandboxed solution you can add your custom JavaScript and jQuery globally. And your custom JavaScript can be uploaded into Style Library and referenced there.
All you need access to is solution gallery to upload, install and activate sandboxed solutions.

Then you can check location.pathname for Upload.aspx, select the checkbox with jQuery and alter it in any way you want. For example:

```
location.pathname.match(/upload\.aspx/i) && $(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);
```

[Referencing javascript files using CustomAction in Sharepoint 2010 Sandboxed Solutions](http://blog.voyta.net/2010/09/12/referencing-javascript-files-using-customaction-in-sharepoint-2010-sandboxed-solutions)